# Python read column with string inside " "

Tags: python

I have a text file which contains the columns as below -

```
 1  a "x y"
 2  b "p q"
 3  c "m n"
 ...
```

Now I want to read each column. So far I have written the simple program

```py
f = open(file,'r')
for line in f:
  columns = line.split()
  name = column[2:4]
  print name

['"x', 'y"']
['"m', 'n"']
['"p', 'q"']
```

But I want to print "x y". Is there any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking but if i understand correctly, Try the .join() method it joins together items of a list.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Are you asking how to combine the elements to create a string? Is there any particular reason you're using Python 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *But I want to print "x y". Is there any suggestion?*

You can use:

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
  for x in [x.split("\"")[1] for x in f]:
    print(x)
```

---

```
x y
p q
m n
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/b22ac5e553)